# C# WPF inotifypropertychanged interferes with data entry

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm not sure if I'm asking this properly. I have a datagrid where column 1 data can come from two different places depending on a switch bit. The first place is a periodic update of the view model column from the model. The second place is if I manually edit a cell of column 1. I have a custom column binding in the XAML code binds to a list of classes. The problem is that when I start typing in data, it gets overwritten by the periodic update. Is there a proper way to design what I am looking to accomplish?

Below is the pseudo code for what is bound to Column 1 of the datagrid.

```
 public int Column1
        {
            get
            {
                if(mySwitch)
                    return this.NumList[0].Data;
                else
                    return this.NumList[0].EditedData;
            }
            set
            {
                if (mySwitch)
                {
                    //this gets set every few seconds
                    this.Numlist[0].Data = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("mydata");
                }
                else
                {   //this gets called only when mySwitch is false and I'm in edit mode.
                    this.Numlist[0].EditedData = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("myediteddata");
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have periodic update of the UI? Where does that come from?

Comment: It's data I'm receiving from some source. Sometimes I want that data...othertimes I want my custom entry...hence the need to edit.

Comment: If you set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` on you binding, you will be able to set a flag indicating that this column should not be updated from behind the scenes.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Do you set mySwitch to true/false somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I set it elsewhere.